# how to use different slider effects in jssor

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

Jssor slider is great and slider there are many feature in that, how we can use different effects and sliders in jssor. In my opinion it was:

```
var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [ {$Duration:800,x:1,$Delay:40,$Cols:6,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Brother:{$Duration:800,x:1,$Delay:40,$Cols:6,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$ZIndex:-10,$Shift:-60}} ];

var jssor_1_options = {
  $AutoPlay: 1,
  $SlideDuration: 800,
  $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
  $CaptionSliderOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
    $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
  },
  $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
  },
  $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
  }
};

var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1_slider", jssor_1_options);
```

Here how I can change transition types like zoom in and zome out, fade in, fade out. Please give some examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use jssor slider composer to add/remove slideshow transitions.

https://www.jssor.com/help/enable-slideshow.html